# Custom Callback made in Keras to stop "Overfitting and Overtraining" all in one is taking too much time to save model and weight

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have made this `CallBack` to stop `Overfitting` specially and `Overtraining` secondly is taking too much time for model to save weights. SO the logic is that I want to save only and only that where `current_val_loss` is always less than `min_val_loss` **AND** less than `min_train_loss`. I want to save that weight as `best_model_weight` and restore that weight after the Training ends. Here is the code for that Callback:

```
class StopOverFit(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  '''
  A class that stops Overfitting by saving the model/weights if val_loss < loss and val_loss < min_val_loss ever encountered
  Adds the functionality of ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping too. Currently works only with "val_loss"
  '''
    
  def __init__(self,filename=None,weights_only=True,restore_weights=False,early_stop=True,
               watch='val_loss',patience=5,stop_at=0.0001,min_delta=0.003):
    '''
    Constructor of the Callback
    args:
        filename: {str} should in the format "epoch: {epoch:02d}- val_loss: {val_loss:.3f}.hdf5"
        weights_only: {bool} whether to save the whole model or just the weights
        restore_weights: {bool} whether to restore the "best" weights at the end of training
        early_stop: {bool} whether to stop he model before reaching the epochs described
        watch: {str} which metri to watch out for
        patience: {int} if model has not improved with there continuous epochs, stop model training
        stop_at: {float} if the model has a metric less than equal to this value, stop training
        min_delta: {float} If the difference between best and current is greater than this, do not consider it as improvement
    '''
    super(StopOverFit,self).__init__()
    self.filename = filename
    self.weights_only = weights_only
    self.best_min_val_loss = np.inf # "best" means without overfitting 
    self.min_loss = np.inf # min train loss
    self.restore = restore_weights
    self.best_weights = None # for restoring weights
    self.early_stop = early_stop 
    self.watch = watch # which metric to watch out for
    self.patience = patience # how many epochs before stopping training
    self.counter = 0 # to get the counter of how many epochs it's been since the last improvement
    self.stop_at = stop_at # stop if the required metric has been achieved
    self.delta = min_delta # if last saved loss has improved more than delta, say it a progress

        
        
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    '''
    Do something when each epoch begins like getting the logs dict and comparing the values
    arguments are provided by the model itself
    args:
      epoch: {int} epoch number. starts with 0
      logs: {dict} dictonary with metrices and losses as key. single value for each key
    '''
    val_loss = logs['val_loss']
    loss = logs['loss']
    val_f1 = logs['val_f1']

    if loss<self.min_loss:
      self.min_loss = loss
    
    if (val_loss<self.best_min_val_loss) and (val_loss<self.min_loss):
      print(f"\nbest val_loss improved from {self.best_min_val_loss:.4f} to {val_loss:.4f}. saving..")
      self.best_min_val_loss = val_loss
      self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
      
      if self.weights_only:
        if self.filename:
          self.model.save_weights('weights-'+self.filename.format(val_loss=val_loss,epoch=epoch+1,val_f1=val_f1))
        else:
          self.model.save_weights('best_weights.h5')
      else:
        if self.filename:
          self.model.save('model-'+self.filename.format(val_loss=val_loss,epoch=epoch+1,val_f1=val_f1))
        else:
          self.model.save('best_model.h5')
    


  def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
    '''
    Do something when when the model end. We'll restore the best_weights
    args:
      logs: {dict} dictonary with metrices and losses as key. key:list pair
    '''
    if self.restore:
      print("\nend of training. Restoring Best Weights")
      self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not setting the criteria to save the weights based on both the validation loss being the lowest thus far AND being below the training loss. Generally the training loss of the previous epoch may be lower than the validation loss for the current epoch, especially in the later epochs. You want to continue training as long as the value loss continues to decrease. To do that you can just use the existing Keras callback EarlyStopping. Monitor validation loss and set  restore_best_weights=True. I also recommend that you include the callback ReduceLROnPlateau. Set it to monitor validation loss. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/)

Comment: Thank you. I know how to use those but I am just asking is is there any problem in the code? I want to know the code is taking so much time in saving.